# Is there any way to get Document Management activity logs using the Forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are currently looking into the monitoring of documents and activities in  BIM360. Webhooks for version added or changed work to a certain extent but only capture so much. 
There is a way to manually export the logs into a csv file and idealy we would want to automate this process so our BI department has data to work with.

Furthermore if not possible, is this something you guys are planning to add to the API in the near future or is it a low prio kinda thing.

Cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry we don't have a direct API to extract that information. There is a built-in UI feature.

Via API you can get each file's version history, but that would require a recursive function to craw all folders & subfolders.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Augusto, coincidentally I have already written such a function to extract all the data for a given folder (including subfolders and the contents of said subfolders) So that might be a good workaround for now ! Thanks again !